# VBA table into outlook, loses proper format

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I'm using the code from Ron De Bruin to embed a table into an email in Outlook (http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm). However, when it goes into the email, my the space between the numbers and then border disppears and the numbers are basically touching it. How can I get this space to stay/come back?

EDIT: HTML Code part follows

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
 .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With




With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     FileName:=TempFile, _
     sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

TempWB.Close Savechanges:=False

Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: What is the result HTML markup?

Comment: Can you add an image of the email body  to see what it looks like on question

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I have edited the question to include the HTML part of the code. Thanks for any help!

Comment: @Omar I just included the photo as well. Thanks!

Comment: try doing this       `Cells(1).Select '<<---- Change` and  `Cells(1).EntireRow.AutoFit '<<-- Add` and  `Cells(1).EntireColumn.AutoFit '<<-- Add`

Comment: @Omar it doesn't change the numbers still being right on the line

Answer (score 0):

Edit <kbd>**CODE**</kbd> From

```
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
```

Change and Add To <kbd>**CODE**</kbd>

```
      Cells(1).Select '<<---- Change
      Cells(1).EntireRow.AutoFit '<<-- Add
      Cells(1).EntireColumn.AutoFit '<<-- Add
```

> Or Format the spread sheet and add column and make the width 0.2 between the numbers and then border

Comment: That unfortunately makes it jump over really far. Is it possible to diminish the scale that the change of the indent makes? Or even just add spaces?

Comment: you could add column and make the width 0.2 between the numbers and then border